# how should i change a route to make it find routes by dotes "."?

Tags: controller, routes, laravel-5.4

I'm doing a project that the tutorial that I'm learning from, has not  the same LARAVEL version as the mine.
so it keeps routing the controllers with dots
but doesn't make any changes to the routing page codes.
like setting or changing the rout name or something like that and for that version it worked fine.
but in my project, server can't recognize that kind of routing.
how should i change the routes to work correctly?

i know for those kind of routes that we add them we can set a name for them to find the route correctly
but I need to set the `/home` route in a way that will work fine but it doesn't matter where do i add the dot in the name of route, **.home** or **home.** , it won't work!

here is my *web.php* code:
`Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');`

and my *controller*:

```
public function index()
    {
        return View('index.index');
    }
```

**localhost:8000/home** works fine
but i need to fix **localhost:8000** routing to be recogniz

Answer (score 0):

it's unclear what you're asking.

You've made an url for `/home` which is named `home`. This means that in your blade templates, you can call

`<a href="{{ route('home') }}">`

The dot can be used as a separation symbol, Naming the route `home.index` usually means: home controller, index method. It can be whatever you like though.

So you likely want to change the route name to `->name('home.index')`

You could then access that using `route('home.index')`

Comment: i had the same problem for `Route::group( ['prefix'=>'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'] , function()
{

 Route::resource('/news','NewsController');
 Route::resource('/dormitory','DormitoryController');
 Route::resource('/conditions','conditionsController');

 Route::get('index' , function() 
 {
  return View('admin.index');
 });

 
 

});` before i add  **'as' => 'admin.'** the routing couldn't work too. and now i don't know how to change like **admin.** to make it recognize routings with dots like it does with slashes.

Comment: try `php artisan route:list` and see what data you get back